# Strange error when trying to Get-ADUser

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I try to list all users in a forest which trust my forest (there is a transitive bi-directional forest trust with between the two) but I'm unable to.

The trusting forest is g.org and I run:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter '*' -SearchScope 2 -Server g.org -Properties DistinguishedName,DisplayName,GivenName,ObjectClass,SamAccountName
```

But get the following error:

```
Get-ADUser : A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ADUser -Filter '*' -SearchScope 2 -Server g.org -Properties Dis ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [Get-ADUser], AuthenticationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

I do succeed with all the other trusting forests.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: What does the inner exception say?  You leave out a pretty important detail in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This smells like an infrastrucutre issue. You should doublecheck if the other Domain can be reached properly. You can also check if you can browse the other Domain with the "Active Directory Users and Computer" or with [AD-Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/adexplorer)

Here are some more things to consider:

- Can the Domain be pinged?
- Switch from the Domain-Name to an individual AD-Server at `Get-ADUSer`
- Make sure the Date/Time is the same for all Domains
- Check that the Domain is on 2008 or later (2003 will not support the PowerShell)
- Try to use Credentials from the other Domain `Get-ADUser -Credentals (Get-Credential)`